# Android Crash Dump data Accessing on Device

Tags: android, crash, crash-dumps

This might be an obvious question but I really don't see how to access a crash dump that occurs on my Samsung Device when testing. I see core dump and then some options to like #*9900* to access it. It tells where the file went, but how do I access the directory from my PC and or copy it over to my PC.  I have kies installed I tried switching also to mass storage but I just don't see how to access file system.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check logcat in eclipse to see the stack trace and also do adb bugreport to see the physical dump. adb pull location/of/files should also pull files off the device.

Comment: when I do adb bugreport I get Failed to connect to dumpstate service

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
Make Sure Application>Development>USB debugging is enabled
Unpluging and re-plugging in your Device
Restarting your Device
Restarting your Computer

But I have a feeling that the kies application maybe interfering with your adb. I know that third party android tools can get in the way of the the official ones, especially when they provide there own adb executables which kies might be doing.